# How to make a call to php code on clicking Ok button in the popup?

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, confirm

I have a PHP code as shown below in which at `Line A` popup is created with buttons `Ok` and `Cancel` and message `hello world`

```
<?PHP
    // ..... some other code

    if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
        $message = "hello world";
        // create a pop up window with $message on it along with "ok" and "cancel" button
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('$message');</script>";   // Line A
    }

    // ..... some other code
?>
```

I am wondering how I can make a call to `secondUser()` function **(as shown below)** on clicking `Ok` button in the popup. Line A in the code above creates `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons with the message `hello world`

I don't want anything to happen on clicking `Cancel` button.

```
<script>
function secondUser () {
    $.ajax({
        url:"login_second_user.php",    //the page containing php script
        type: "post",    //request type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {registration: "success", name: "xyz", email: "abc@gmail.com"},
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result.abc);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to create a function which calls `confirm()` to get the response from the user. Inside the same function, you can call `secondUser()` based on that response.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I am wondering if you can give me pointer how we can do that.

Comment: Just write a function directly above your `secondUser()` function, and run that function instead of `confirm()` in your PHP code.

Comment: `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>if (confirm('$message')) { secondUser(); };</script>";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried your code. All my code is in the file admin.php. At the top, I have a php code and at the bottom I have placed a javascript. On clicking `Ok` button, it says `secondUser()` is not defined.

Comment: Well you have to have the js defined before you can run it. Try moving it into the <head>

Comment: Sorry, I am getting confused here. My file structure is PHP + JS. Here is the [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/eAhTp) for my file admin.php. I am wondering if you can have a look and give me pointers.